# Class diagram for object-orientated card game to deal cards up to 21 points

Tags: java, class-diagram

I have been asked to create a class diagram for a simple card game - 21 (aka Black Jack). The game doesn't need to take into consideration of suits and there is no Kings, Queens or Jacks. The Ace is just a 1. So the Ace doesn't count as 11 or 1, instead there is no Ace just a 1.

I am horrible at designing class diagrams and I do not have a lot of experience. But considering that this is StackOverflow, I recognise that I have to research and attempt to complete this task prior to posting this question. So this is all I could conjure up, as follows:

[image]

**The criteria for the class diagram is as follows:**

The Language being used is Java (no that it really matters),

The class diagram needs to show the members of the class for both the individual cards and how they fit together as part of a deck of cards (as I have attempted above).

Comment: Hi that's actually quite a good start. I would put deck on the left and card on the right. Then I would write on the arrow to indicate a "1 to many" composition relationship. In Java this could be for example a "Set<Card>" (given that they have suits) or a "List<Card>" otherwise (if you need to have duplicates).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @vikingsteve, will the deck need any variables or functions and will the card need any functions included? Also when you say 'List<Card>' what exactly do you refer to? - It is just that i am horrible with class diagrams and do not understand all the terminology.

Comment: List<Card> is a list holding cards, this is java terminology. When you ask about variables and functions, ask yourself, if you were implementing this, would you need any? What method calls would there be in your program? Which classes would they belong to?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Fadeway, I have little knowledge of Java - I am a college students and object orientated is a study unit that I am doing on the side. So I am a bit unsure what classes and variables would be required in order to make this game. Therefore i was hoping that someone could generate a class digram that states exactly what I need to create the game - I have tried researching this but have had little luck, as the explanations are a little technical (terminology)

Comment: Providing complete solutions here is rare, this goes double for homework. Here's a tip: one action in your game would be drawing the next card. Therefore, you'll need a method somewhere that handles that. But seriously, you'll have more luck with a question asking for resources to learn this stuff as a non-programmer (probably on a different site on the network). I'd give you links myself but I'm not aware of any offhand.

Comment: Write down, in English or your native language, the directions for playing your version of BlackJack.  Keep breaking down the directions into more and more sentences until you could write code for each sentence.  Then create your class diagram from your written instructions.

Comment: It sounds like you'll need a few more classes here. Maybe the "Dealer", who is in charge of the deck, can draw a card from the deck and give it to the "Player". Etc etc. In the Deck <-> Card relationship, the deck will basically need 3 methods: reset (take all the cards back and shuffle), dealCard (deals a card) and count (count the remaining cards).